# How to use the provider to update the data state asynchronously?

Tags: flutter

There are two tab pages in a page. When the tab page is switched, the data state is loaded from the cache. How can the provider asynchronously update the data state?

Answer (score 0):

1-you can use *enums* to indicate the state of the data

```
enum DataState{loading,success,error,idle}
```

2- add *instance of the enum* in your class of that extends `changeNotifier`

```
class YourClass extends ChangeNotifier {

DataState state = DataState.idle;
//the rest of your code
}
```

3- change the *state* of the `state` inside the function that updates the data

```
Future updateData()async{
state = DataState.loading;
notifyListenrs();
await data;
if(data!=null)
state = DataState.sucess;
else 
state = DataState.error;
notifyListeners();
}
```

4- make *switch statement* inside the UI to return different widgets according to the

```
current state

switch(model.state)
{
case DataState.loading:
return CircularProgressIndicator();
break;
case DataState.succuess:
return showDataWidget();
break;
//and so on
}
```